# Having a camera follow a ball in unity without having the camera roll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a golf game in unity, where I have a camera orbitting a ball based on mouse x and y input. The camera controller code works fine until I start applying force to the ball. Please see camera controller code below:

```
void ControlCamera() 
{
    // Do Nothing if Locked
    if (cameraLocked)
        return;

    // Handle Zoom
    myCamera.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(myCamera.transform.position, transform.position, Input.mouseScrollDelta.y);

    // Handle Y Transformation
    Transform yTransform = myCamera.transform;
    yTransform.RotateAround(transform.position, Vector3.left, Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * cameraSensitivity);
    if (yTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.x < maxXRot && yTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.x > minXRot)
    {
        myCamera.transform.rotation = yTransform.rotation;
        myCamera.transform.position = yTransform.position;
    }

    // Handle X Transformation
    myCamera.transform.RotateAround(transform.position, Vector3.down, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * cameraSensitivity);

    // Prevent Z Skew
    Quaternion currentRotation = myCamera.transform.rotation;
    float xRot = currentRotation.eulerAngles.x;
    float yRot = currentRotation.eulerAngles.y;
    currentRotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRot, yRot, 0);
    myCamera.transform.rotation = currentRotation;
}
```

The camera object is a child of the ball object, and rolls with the ball when a force is applied. I've tried detatching the camera object from the ball object which breaks the camera object (it no longer follows the ball because it's no longer a child).

Any ideas as to how I can keep this code nice and simple as it it is now and prevent the roll of the camera while still following the ball?

Comment: Who cares abut the rotation?  The ball is moving along a straight line.  So the camera should be moving along the line at a speed.  The speed you have to take the rotational speed and convert to a speed along the line.  So if the ball has a diameter of 10 and rotates once a second.  Then the speed is 10 per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to have inside the ball gameObject 2 childs, one with the ball that will rotate, and another one with the camera. This way the camera will follow the parent gameObject, who doesn't rotate (but you should update the position).

The other one, and the one I like it the most is to do not child the camera on to the ball gameObject, just update the camera position from the ball position, JUST the position, not the rotation. Something like:

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour 
{
      public GameObject ball;

      void Update() 
      {
          Vector3 pos = ball.transform.position;
          transform.position = pos;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Perfect, I assigned this to an empty GameObject which follows the camera, and the camera is a child of this game object. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need for creating a child object, just add this to your camera.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + new Vector3(0f, 3f, -6f);
        transform.position = desiredPosition;
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```